# How can I check if a particular property setter is called on a Mock object?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

For the given mock object below, how can I check if the WashCar(ICar car) method is setting the TiresWashed property?

```
public interface ICar 
{
    string Model {get;set;}
    bool TiresWashed {get; set;}
    bool WindowsWashed {get; set; }
}

    [TestMethod]
    public vouid MyUnitTest()
    {
    ICar mockCar = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICar>();
    CarServiceUtility.WashCar(mockCar);

    //Assert if PrepareCar method is called: (this is why I had mock)
    mockCar.AssertWasCalled(c=>c.PrepareCar());

    //TODO 
    // Assert if mockCar.TiresWashed is set with any value
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729267/rhino-mocks-assertwascalled-multiple-times-on-property-getter-using-aaa

Comment: It is a good hint there but cannot exactly find my answer. But +1 for the link. Thx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/49587062/RhinoMocksAAAQuickReference):

```
mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Name ="Bob");
```

or

```
mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Name =Arg.Is("Bob"));
```

or

```
mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Name =Arg<string>.Is.NotNull);
```

Answer (score 0):

How I managed to do it after the_ajp's link is:

```
mockCar.AssertWasCalled(car => { var dummy = car.TiresWashed; }, options 
 => options.SetPropertyWithArgument(Arg<object>.Is.Anything));
```